# Futter bloc how we can use multiple events and states on one page

Tags: flutter, mobile, bloc, cubit

We have more than one event structure in flutter, but as the events change, we lose the values of the previous event. When we switch to a new event and state, how can we still reflect the data of the previous event on the page?

Comment: Would storing all data needed in the state (from the event) work ? If you pass it onto the next states, it'll still be there, unless a new event changed it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.